# Excel VBA copy to another range using cells

Tags: vba, excel

I'm having some trouble with my code:

```
Worksheets("Week 1").Range(Cells(4, ColNo), Cells(5, ColNo)).Value = Worksheets("Count").Range(Cells(4, 2), Cells(5, 2)).Value
```

If I change it to

```
Worksheets("Week 1").Range(Cells(4, ColNo), Cells(5, ColNo)).Value = Worksheets("Count").Range("B4:B5").Value
```

It works fine, can anyone help?

Comment: `Cells` is not fully qualified so it refers to the currently active sheet

Comment: `['Week 1'!A4:A5].Columns(ColNo) = [Count!B4:B5]`

Comment: Thanks Robin, adding .address after the cells function worked.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by adding .address after the cells

```
Worksheets("Count").Range(Cells(4, 2).address, Cells(5, 2).address).Value
```

Comment: If that code runs when the active sheet is a `Chart`, it will fail because a `Chart` sheet doesn't have `Cells`.  It is better to fully qualify the references, e.g. as `Worksheets("Count").Range(Worksheets("Count").Cells(4, 2), Worksheets("Count").Cells(5, 2)).Value` (or using a `With Worksheets("Count")` block, `.Range(.Cells(4, 2), .Cells(5, 2)).Value`)